# VSTS build step changes log trails

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS builds, is there a way I can know who have make changes in build steps?
Can I get history builds?

The reason for this is, we have a big team. Many time it happens that someone changes the build step for some reason and we never know who made the changes and why.

Like in git repo, we know which file is changed by who and why (in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In VSTS builds, is there a way I can know who have make changes in build steps? Can I get history builds?

The answer is yes. You could check the **History** of the build definition:

[image]

Click on the three horizontal dots and we will get an option compare difference, through which we can know the details of the pipeline modification. If the modifier adds a note when saving the modification, we can also know the reason for the build pipeline modification.